# Firestore pagination in angular

Tags: angular, pagination, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to get pagination to my page.

Url to the site: https://pettemm.github.io/angular/home

Url to the code: https://github.com/pettemm/angular

This is the Service that grabs my items:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreCollection, 
AngularFirestoreDocument } from 'angularfire2/firestore';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Item } from '../models/item';


    @Injectable()
    export class ItemService {

    itemsCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<Item>;
    items: Observable<Item[]>;
    itemDoc: AngularFirestoreDocument<Item>;

    constructor(public afs: AngularFirestore) { 

    this.itemsCollection = this.afs.collection('items', ref => 
    ref.orderBy('title','desc'));

this.items = this.itemsCollection.snapshotChanges().map(changes => {
return changes.map(a =>{
  const data = a.payload.doc.data() as Item;
  data.id = a.payload.doc.id;
  return data;
  });
});
}

getItems(){
return this.items;    
   }
```

This is my component:

```
   import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
   import { ItemService } from '../../services/item.service';
   import { Item } from '../../models/item';

   @Component({
   selector: 'app-items',
   templateUrl: './items.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./items.component.css']
   })


    export class ItemsComponent implements OnInit {
    items: Item[];
    editState: boolean = false;
    itemToEdit: Item;

    constructor(private itemService: ItemService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
    this.itemService.getItems().subscribe(items => {     
    this.items = items;
    });
    }
```

On the first page Home i'm using firebase and i want to paginate so i only who 2 items, and then you can click next to show the other two. I know about the startAt and endAt, but can't figure out how to use that.

On the other sides mat and traning i'm using firestore. When i swap between home and mat and back to home again, the items won't update, why?

Answer (score 0):

You have to do it after your orderBy

```
 this.itemsCollection = this.afs.collection('items', ref => 
        ref.orderBy('title','desc').starAt(x).endAt(x);
```

**OR**

```
 this.itemsCollection = this.afs.collection('items', ref => 
    ref.orderBy('title','desc').endAt(x);
```

Where `X` is the index of the items